# Service reference existing under local namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

The following diagram refers

[image]

The idea is to expose the database schema to the application via the WCF service. This is working.

The problem is that the service reference exists under the application's namespace, which means that all the database entities exposed by the service also does, i.e. accessing an entity from the service can be accomplished  with `Service.Entity` but with `Application.Service.Entity` from the application's perspective.

I just want to know if it's possible to have a service reference, and the members exposed by it, exist outside the local namespace.

Expanding the service reference object and opening the Reference.cs allows you to edit the generated code and, just for testing, I removed the auto-inserted local namespace from all the member references in that file and it solved the problem. But doing that every time is not ideal and I was hoping there was a way of simply excluding the local namespace when adding a service reference.

Comment: First of all, I hope you're not just exposing the entire database as a wieb service. Unless your database was explicitly intended to be exposed that way, it probably has things in it that you wouldn't want the consumers of a web service shouldn't see. Things like junction tables or other implementation specifics. Consider exposing an Entity Framework conceptual model instead.

Comment: Second, I don't understand why you don't just specify a unique namespace when you add the service reference.

Comment: 1) Only what is necessary will be exposed; 2) A namespace has to be provided when the service reference is added, but it's prefixed with the local name space, so if I specify the service reference's namespace as `Cheese` and the local namespace is `Bacon` then I can only access the entities exposed by the service as `Bacon.Cheese.<entity_name>` but I want to be able to access it with `Cheese.<entity_name>`.

Comment: Then add `using Bacon;` to the top of your class.

Comment: But then `Cheese` is still a sub-namespace of `Bacon`. When I specify the service reference namespace as `Cheese` Visual Studio generates the Reference.cs file with `namespace <local_namespace>.Cheese { }` but I want it to be `namespace Cheese { }`. Here is a possible solution, but it still requires some slightly lower level configuration when consuming the service: http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2010/05/31/Customizing-Visual-Studio-generated-service-reference-namespaces.aspx

Comment: I'm really not sure why you care so much about the specific namespace - or why so many other developers do not care.

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't get to this point. I'm attempting the serialisation of Expressions Trees. All types are serialised on the application side and passed to the WCF service where they are re-typed based on the name passed from the application. If the type created by the service reference exists under the application's namespace - `Bacon.Cheese.Type` - while the service's types do not - `Cheese.Type` - then the service won't be able to resolve the types again - `Bacon.Cheese.Type != Cheese.Type`.

Comment: I think you'll need to use the "Reuse types" feature, so that the client and server are actually using the same types, and not proxy types.